# How to find and format multiple matching words with Regex in Word document using VB script

Tags: regex, automation, ms-word, vbscript

I have a **word** document in which I have to do the formatting of the words using VB script. The text can be as follows :

```
hello <bu ABC bu>,   We are pleased to confirm our offer of employment to you. The terms and conditions that will apply to your employment with are set forth in this letter and Exhibit A attached hereto and incorporated herein by reference together, the “Agreement”
```

You have been offered and accepted the position of  , presently reporting to . Your start date is expected to be

The words which are written inside tag  needs to be bold and underlined. Currently I have written a VBscript which will find the text given as argument and make it bold and underline as required.

But to make the solution/script more dynamic, I want the script to match Regular Expression pattern which I have written : (?<=(<bu))[a-zA-Z0-9 -:/\[]()]+(?=(bu>))

The script I have written :

```
Option Explicit

Function Macro1()

    Dim strFilePath
    strFilePath = "C:\Users\<UserID>\Documents\OfferLetterTemplate.docx"
    
    Dim strTextToReplace
    strTextToReplace = "<bu XYZ bu>"
    
    Dim Word, objDoc, objSelection

    Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Word.Visible = True

    Dim wordfile
    Set wordfile = Word.Documents.Open(strFilePath)

    Set objDoc = Word.ActiveDocument
    Set objSelection = Word.Selection
    
    objSelection.Find.Forward = True
    objSelection.Find.MatchWholeWord = False
    objSelection.Find.ClearFormatting
    objSelection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    objSelection.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold = True
    objSelection.Find.Replacement.Font.Underline = True
    objSelection.Find.Text = strTextToReplace
    objSelection.Find.Replacement.Text = ""

    objSelection.Find.Execute , , , , , , , 0, , , 2
    
    wordfile.save
    Word.Quit
    
End Function


call Macro1
```

Can someone help me how I can search for the RegEx which I have given above and format all the matching occurrences at once?

Comment: Why are you not using a Word template with all the formatted boilerplate content already in place?

Comment: @macropod here I am trying to generate an offer letter for every new joiner, so the text given inside <b b> will be dynamic and will come from an excel sheet. Will boilerplate content help me to do so?

Comment: Why not use Mailmerge? For many merges, no script or code is needed.

Comment: «I am trying to generate an offer letter for every new joiner, so the text given inside <b b> will be dynamic» In which case nothing about the formatting is relevant - a straightforward Find/Replace without any reference to font attributes is sufficient if the target text is already formatted appropriately. You are over-thinking this. You could just as easily use a plain Find/Replace or, if needed, a *wildcard* Find/Replace on, say «ABC»